Openssl Decoder failing
I am trying to make function that encodes EVP_PKEY into a DER buffer and then decode it from the buffer into EVP_PKEY but for somereason, it is failing. Here's the code :
EVP_PKEY *keyGeneration(){
    char *pcPrivateKey  = NULL,*pcPublicKey = NULL;
    int size;
    EVP_PKEY *privateKey = EVP_EC_gen("secp384r1");
FREE_AND_RETURN:
    return privateKey;
}
int DecodeECDERKey(EVP_PKEY **pkey,const unsigned char *pucBuffer){
    OSSL_DECODER_CTX *dctx;
    const char *format = "DER";   /* NULL for any format */
    const char *structure = "NULL"; /* any structure */
    const char *keytype = "EC";   /* NULL for any key */
    const unsigned char *pass = NULL;
    const unsigned char *data = pucBuffer;
    size_t datalen = sizeof(pucBuffer);
    dctx = OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey(privateKey, format, structure, keytype, OSSL_KEYMGMT_SELECT_KEYPAIR, NULL, NULL);
    if (dctx == NULL) {
         opensslError();
         printf("OSSL_DECODER failed\n");
         return 0;
    }
    if (pass != NULL)
        OSSL_DECODER_CTX_set_passphrase(dctx, pass, strlen(pass));
    if (OSSL_DECODER_from_data(dctx, &data, &datalen)) {
        printf("DECODED SUCCESSFULLY!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to decode the Key\n");
    }
    OSSL_DECODER_CTX_free(dctx);
}


int EncodeEVPToDER(EVP_PKEY *privateKey,unsigned char **puPrivateKey,size_t *sDerPrivateKeyLen){
    int iReturn = 0;
    OSSL_ENCODER_CTX *ctx = OSSL_ENCODER_CTX_new_for_pkey(privateKey, EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR, "DER", "type-specific", NULL);
    if((ctx != NULL) && (OSSL_ENCODER_to_data(ctx, puPrivateKey, sDerPrivateKeyLen) == 1) && (sDerPrivateKeyLen> 0))
    {
        OSSL_ENCODER_CTX_free(ctx);
    }
    else{
       printf("Encode failed\n");
    }
    iReturn = 1;
FREE_AND_RETURN:
    return iReturn;
}

void testECKeyGenerationAndCSRGeneration(){
    EVP_PKEY *privateKey = keyGeneration();
    if(privateKey == NULL){
        printf("private key is null\n");
        return;
    }
    char *puPrivateKey = NULL;
    size_t privateKeyLen;
    if(0 == EncodeEVPToDER(privateKey,&puPrivateKey,&privateKeyLen)){
        printf("ENCODE FAILED\n");
        return;
    }
    DebugBufferPrint("PRIVATE KEY : ",puPrivateKey,privateKeyLen);
    EVP_PKEY *newPrivateKey = NULL;
    DecodeECDERKey(&newPrivateKey,puPrivateKey);
    opensslError();
    return;
}

The opensslError() function printed out the error and it was saying :
error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
What am I doing wrong here ? I used this as reference : text

sizeof(pucBuffer) gives the length of a POINTER not of the data in the buffer. You need to pass and use the value in the caller's privateKeyLen -- and usually a copy (as you have) because the call modifies it (and the pointer) losing the prior values which often are needed later (though not for your toy example). The example you link would work only if buffer is defined as an array in the code like unsigned char buffer[] = {0x30,0x81,0xa4,2,1,1,4,0x30...} // the DER bytes

Sure, I will try this.
